# I don't understand how how they came to these equations

Tags: inequality

Trying to understand a particular equation, and it mentions these inequalities but i don't fully understand the logic of how they solved for n and m:

[image]

Hope some one can explain :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $$-\frac{N}{2} \leq n < \frac{N}{2}$$

Add $\frac{N}{2}$ to everything and you get 
$$ 0 \leq n + \frac{N}{2} < N$$

Comparing this with $0 \leq n' < N$, we can set $n' = n + \frac{N}{2}$.

Comment: Ah thanks, that made it much simpler to understand :)